# Access a file from the applied plugin

Tags: android, gradle, plugins, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

So consider I have a plugin: com.example.JAMplugin

That JAMplugin operates from a

```
class Main{
    @TaskAction
       public void mainprocess() {
       }
 }
```

The same package holds another class called Encode.
This plugin is applied in my android project.
How can my android project access the Encode class inside the plugin. Any solutions on that?

Edit: If there is a class A inside my android project, I want to access the static method inside the Encode class which is in the plugin.